# If 4+7+2 = 281435, 7+3+9 = 212781, 6+2+7 = 121456, and 2+8+5 = 164036, then what would 8+4+6 equal?

Tags: puzzle

**I wanna check my answer that it's Right or wrong?** as there is no answer given for this question.

According to me:

8+4+6= 32 24 **72** <- is the correct Answer.

**This is the way how I found my answer:**

To get initial 4 digits of all mathematical statements, if have to multiply middle digit by first initial digit to get the 1st and 2nd digits of our answer and then by multiplying middle digit to the last digit to get the 3rd and 4th digits.

Now, the Last two digits (5th and 6th) follows specific rules and properties:

How ?

Now let me explain each case one by one.

**1st :** 4+7+2 = 2814**35**

How here 35 comes:

If we multiply the middle digit 7 by the initial digit 4 and by last digit 2 and add their products and then subtract it by middle digit 7 we get = **35**.

We should apply this way of getting last two digits in this priority order if:

1. Middle digit is greater than initial and last digits.
2. Middle digit is the odd digit.

Now,

**2nd :** 7+3+9=2127**81**

Here how 81 comes:

Multiply the middle digit 3 by rest initial digit 7 and by last digit 9 and then again add their product.

We get 48.

Now reverse this no, it becomes (84) and subtracts it by middle no. (3) we get = **81**

Now this way of getting last two digits follows this priority order:

1. All digits must be odd.
2. The middle digit must be smaller than initial and last digits.

Now, for

**3rd :** 6+2+7 = 1214**56**

Now, how 56 comes up:

If we multiply the last 7 digit by initial digit 6 and by middle digit 2 and add their products we get = **56**.

Now this way of getting last two digits follows these priority order of rules:

1. Initial and last digit must be greater than the middle digit.
2. Middle digit must be even.

Now the last case,

**4th :** 2+8+5 = 1640 **36**

How 36 comes up:

Multiply the middle digit 8 by initial digit 2 and last digit 5 and then add their product we get 56.

Now, increment the value of initial digit(2) till it becomes 1 less than the last digit.(5)

Now, our initial digit 2 becomes 4 which is one less than last digit 5.

Now, multiply the updated initial digit(4) by 5.

And subtract their product by 56 we get = **36**.

Now this way of getting last two digits follows these rules:

1. The initial digit and last digit must be smaller than the middle one.
2. The middle digit must even.

**Now, here comes our question :
8+4+6 = ?**

Observe this question now.

1.The initial digit and last digit is greater than the middle one.

We came to know that this question satisfies case 2nd and 3rd.

Now, we have to apply one more case rule to select the right one.

Now in our question, the middle digit(4) is even.

So, among these two cases.

Our question follows Case 3rd.

Therefore, by applying the way of getting last two digits of case 3rd:

Multiply the last digit 6 by initial digit 8 and by the middle digit 4 and then add their products we get our answer which is = 72.

So, finally

**8+4+6 = 3224 72 is the correct answer.**

Now, I wanna check that the way of getting this answer is wrong or right? As I don't have any reference to check my answer.

If anybody knows this, please give your answer on this. I will be Thankful to you :)

Comment: I think that there is a puzzle site where they specialise in this sort of problem.

Comment: To me it looks like you have separate rules for each of the examples for the last two digits. You could just as well have made up a fifth rule that make the last two be $42$ instead...

Comment: Here is the site that I suggested: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/.  This type of puzzle seems to be popular there.

Comment: _shudders at horrible abuse of equals sign_

Comment: @badjohn Thanks Badjon for your suggestion :)

Comment: @skyking curious to know how?

Comment: @HimanshuVerma Take the product of the middle and the first number and then add the middle and the last number (ie $8\times4+4+6=42$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's probably not the equal sign that is abused, but rather the addition sign. What we're looking for here seem to be a ternary operator of some kind (or maybe a binary operator).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Also shuddering but, unfortunately, this sort of puzzle seems to have become popular.

Comment: @skyking that's right. But, I calculated it by using the Case 3rd rules in their priority order.

Comment: @HimanshuVerma Who's priority order? As I said it look like you arbitrarily choose rules for the first four cases and use some criterion for them as arbitrarily looking - this means that one could as well make up a fifth rule with a fifth criterion to make the result whatever one likes. This arbitrary way of coming to a result makes the answer quite opinion based (especially when one have that much liberty in coming up with the rules).

Comment: @skyking you are right.
Let's wait for the proper right answer.

Comment: The right way to solve this :

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52600/can-you-find-the-pattern